# finding differences across a row with awk

Tags: awk

I have a table in which most of the values in a given row are the same.  What I want to pull out are any rows where at least one of the values is different.  I’ve figured out how to do that with something like this

```
awk -F "\t" '{if (($4!=$5)&&($5!=$6)&&($6!=$7)) print $0;}'
```

The only problem is there are 40 some odd columns to compare.  Is there a more elegant way to compare multiple columns for differences.  BTW – these are non numerical values so a fancy math trick wont work.

Thanks All.  I'm a newbee so I have to admit that I don't understand all of the commands, etc. but I can look it up from here.  Not sure who's suggestion I'll go with but I learn more from concrete examples than I do from textbook explanations so having these different solutions is a big help with my learning curve.

Answer (score 6):

A fancy math trick might not work but how about:

```
$ cat file
one one one one two
two two two two two
three four four five

$ awk '{f=$0;gsub($1,"")}NF{print f}' file 
one one one one two
three four four five
```

First we store the line in original state `f=$0` then we do a global substitution on everything matching the first field, if all fields are the same then nothing will be left therefor `NF` will be 0 and nothing will be printed else we print the original line.

Your script starts at `$4` which suggests you are only interested in changes from this field on in which case:

```
$ awk '{f=$0;gsub($4,"")}NF>3{print f}' file
```

Comment: awesome, out of the box  +1

Comment: Sorry! It was really a crap! Sorry for that! I deleted. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `for` loop:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ for(i=4;i<NF;i++) if ($i != $(i+1)) { print; next } }' file
```

Adjust accordingly. HTH.

Comment: This will print each line `n` times where `n` is number of fields that different per line, you probably want a `next` in there.

Answer (score 0):

If any field differs from some other field, then either it differs from field 1, or field 1 differs from some other field (by definition).  So just loop from 2 to NF (number of fields) comparing it against all other fields:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF ;i++) if ($i != $1) { print; next; }}'
```

You can tune this to ignore leading fields (e.g., start at 5 and compare against $4) as needed.